# How can i make sure the user ends up entering an integer?

Tags: java

I'm making a function in Java that needs an integer input. My code is this:

```
System.out.println("Input the year");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)
this.error = true
while (this.error = true) {
    try {
        this.year = scan.nextInt;
        this.error = false;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Try again");
        this.year = -1;
    }
}
```

When I execute it, if the user inputs something that's not an integer, it just prints the error message over and over forever, without letting the user input something else. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: be careful: ***while (this.error = true)***

Comment: This code wouldn't compile. So you can't run it. If you ask question about code that doesn't work, then post that code, not some other fake code, that could contain other unrelated problems, and could not contain the original error anymore.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Sorry, this code wouldn't compile: it misses some semicolata, it says `scan.nextInt`, while `nextInt` is a function and would thus need parantheses, and it says `this.error = true`, while this is no comparison, but an assignment -- which could be the problem here.

However, as long as you don't post code, which would actually work, no one knows whether it's just a typo or a real problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `hasNextInt()` method

```
if(scan.hasNextInt()){
   //your code
}
```

See detailed description of [hasNextInt()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnextint.htm) method